# Accessing soap over https in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, web-services, soap, https

I have a server that i am hosting on another computer with axis2 and apache. IM simply trying to connect to it over https.

```
CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding(SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement());

binding.Elements.Add(new HttpsTransportBindingElement());
EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress("https://othercomputer/axis2/services/DataModel");
DataClient client = new DataClient(binding, endpoint);
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "a";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "a12345";
return client;
```

I get a communication exception was unhandled by user code with this code, am i doing it right?

**Edit** with further requested info:
Heres the exception:

> An error occurred while trying to make a request to URI 'https://othercomputer/axis
>   /services/DataModel'. This could be due to attempting to access a service in a cross-
>   domain way without a proper cross-domain policy in place, or a policy that is 
>   unsuitable for SOAP services. You may need to contact the owner of the service to 
>   publish a cross-domain policy file and to ensure it allows SOAP-related HTTP headers 
>   to be sent. This error may also be caused by using internal types in the web service 
>   proxy without using the InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute. Please see the inner 
>   exception for more details.

The authentication is basic authentication, one of my coworkers thinks its a problem with the certificate and thought that it might be because the certificate is self-generated.

Comment: We would need a bunch more info before much useful information can be provided.

1) what kind of security model is configured in the service (assume basic authentication but you want to know for sure)?

2) What details from the communication exception can you provide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its being treated as a cross-domain call.  You need to add a [clientaccesspolicy.xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955(v=vs.95).aspx) file that is accessible through the same server that you are making the SOAP call to.